# $f(t)=\text{det}(A+tB)$ is continuous for symmetric positive semi-definite matrices $A$ and $B$?

Tags: continuity, matrix-calculus, positive-semidefinite

We have any symmetric positive semi-definite matrices $A$ and $B$
where $\text{det}B=0$.

> A function $f(t)=\text{det}(A+tB)$ is continuous on $t\in[0,1]$?

$f(t_{1})-f(t_{2})=\text{det}(A+t_{1}B)-\text{det}(A+t_{2}B)$. From
here, I can't go farther. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know any formula for the determinant, or any calculation rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding out $f(t)=\det(A+tB)$ using the formula for the determinant
shows that $f(t)$ is a polynomial in $t$. All polynomials are continuous
on all of $\Bbb R$. This is true for all matrices $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks!